# Julia vs Python implementation for https://projecteuler.net/problem=2. This was very strange to me and I don't know where I am messing up in Julia

Tags: python, julia

Python implementation

```py
import numpy as np

# Function to generate the Fibonacci series
def fibonacci_fun(fib_series_fun, num_terms_fun):

    # Initialize the first value in series
    first_num_fun = 1

    # Append the first value to series
    fib_series_fun.append(first_num_fun)

    # Initialize the value preceeding the first number; technically always 0 but 1 in this problem
    num_bef_start_fun = 1

    # Add the first_num to the num_bef_start value and append it
    next_num_fun = first_num_fun + num_bef_start_fun
    fib_series_fun.append(next_num_fun)

    # While we do not have num_terms number of elements in Fibonacci series, repeat
    while len(fib_series_fun) != num_terms_fun:

        # Add the previous 2 numbers of the series to itself
        new_num_fun = fib_series_fun[len(fib_series_fun)-2] + fib_series_fun[len(fib_series_fun)-1];
        
        fib_series_fun.append(new_num_fun)

    return fib_series_fun

# Main function
def main():

    # Define the number of terms in Fibonacci series
    num_terms = 25

    # Define empty array of Int16 to store Fibonacci sereis values
    fib_series = []

    # Run the fibonacci_fun to get the Fibonacci series
    fib_series = fibonacci_fun(fib_series, num_terms)
    print(fib_series)

    fib_series = np.array(fib_series)

    # Values less than 4 million
    values_less_than = fib_series[fib_series < 4000000]

    # Get only the even values in the Fibonacci series
    even_values_less_than_fib_series = values_less_than[values_less_than % 2 == 0]
    print(even_values_less_than_fib_series)

    sum_of_fib_series = sum(even_values_less_than_fib_series)
    print("The sum of even values in the Fibonacci series is %d.\n" %sum_of_fib_series)

    print("Process finished!")

main()
```

Julia Implementation

```
using Printf

# Function to generate the Fibonacci series
function fibonacci_fun(fib_series_fun, num_terms_fun)

    # Initialize the first value in series
    first_num_fun = 1

    # Append the first value to series
    append!(fib_series_fun, first_num_fun)

    # Initialize the value preceeding the first number; technically always 0 but 1 in this problem
    num_bef_start_fun = 1

    # Add the first_num to the num_bef_start value and append it
    next_num_fun = first_num_fun + num_bef_start_fun
    append!(fib_series_fun, next_num_fun)

    # While we do not have num_terms number of elements in Fibonacci series, repeat
    while length(fib_series_fun) != num_terms_fun

        # Add the previous 2 numbers of the series to itself
        new_num_fun = fib_series_fun[length(fib_series_fun)-1] + fib_series_fun[length(fib_series_fun)];
        
        append!(fib_series_fun, new_num_fun)
    end

    return fib_series_fun

end

# Main function
function main()

    # Define the number of terms in Fibonacci series
    num_terms = 25

    # Define empty array of Int16 to store Fibonacci sereis values
    global fib_series = Int16[]

    # Run the fibonacci_fun to get the Fibonacci series
    fib_series = fibonacci_fun(fib_series, num_terms)
    println(fib_series)

    # Values less than 4 million
    values_less_than = fib_series[fib_series .< 4000000]

    # Get only the even values in the Fibonacci series
    even_values_less_than_fib_series = values_less_than[values_less_than .% 2 .== 0]
    println(even_values_less_than_fib_series)

    sum_of_fib_series = sum(even_values_less_than_fib_series)
    @printf("The sum of even values in the Fibonacci series is %d.\n", sum_of_fib_series)

    println("Process finished!")

end

main()
```

Python Implementation Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393]

[    2     8    34   144   610  2584 10946 46368]
```

The sum of even values in the Fibonacci series is 60696.

Julia Implementation Output:

```
Int16[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, -19168, 9489, -9679]

Int16[2, 8, 34, 144, 610, 2584, 10946, -19168]
```

The sum of even values in the Fibonacci series is -4840.
Process finished!

Comment: Its because you are using 16 bit signed integers in your Julia implementation. The highest positive interger value for that type is 32,767, anything above that will be seen as a negative int

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: You are using a number that exceeds the upper limit of Int16, which causes it to "loop back through" with the remainder, returning a negative number.

Julia has Concrete Typing(like Int16), and Abstract Typing(like Int). A general rule is that you should use the Concrete typed versions for data storage, as its more efficient(which is what it is being used for in your code- so that's good). The difference being that Int will act normally no matter the input size, and Int16 limits itself to a certain number of bits, so it has bounds. The bounds for Int16 are (-2^15 , 2^15 - 1).

The values from 46368 and up are above the bounds, so they act wonky.

So you could solve your problem by changing:

```
global fib_series = Int64[]
```

or, if you wanted to:

```
global fib_series = Int[]
```